# Gcm MessageTooBig with payload < 4 kb

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send message via gcm. The message payload is

```
{"header": "\u041d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u043c\u0435\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0440\u0438\u044f\u0442\u0438\u0435", "message": "\u0428\u043e\u0443 \"\u042d\u041f\u0418\u0427\u0415\u0421\u041a\u0418\u0419 \u041f\u0420\u041e\u0412\u0410\u041b!\"", "number": "118"}
```

It is about 300 bytes long only, including *all* symbols. Everything works fine, when i send the message to 7 different keys. But when i send the message to 36 keys, MessageTooBig is returned for all keys (even for those keys, that were successfully delivered at previous step).

How can i handle this? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Someone can confirm or dismiss if I'm wrong, but if you mean notification keys, then it sounds like each message towards a key is being counted towards your payload. 7*300byes = ~2kb, while 36*300byes = ~10kb.

Comment: definitely, this was an error in my code, so the question may be marked as invalid. thx.